# Partial boldface of '\n' when using minted with BW style for Haskell highlighting

Tags: minted

I'm using minted with BW style and lmodern fonts for syntax highlighting of Haskell code.

The character '\n' (same for '\*x*' for any *x*) is coming out strangely: the first quotation mark and the backslash are boldface, while the n and the second quotation mark are in normal typewriter font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{bw}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{haskell}
f '\n'
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image: f boldface quotation mark boldface backslash normal n normal quotation mark]

I think the correct behaviour would be to put nothing in boldface. I can't use escapeinside to force this to come out correctly, because it doesn't work with strings.

(I'm using the lighttt option of lmodern to make the distinction between boldface and normal typewriter font more obvious, but the same thing happens if I don't use it.)

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the lexer that doesn't handle `\` special characters. Fixing the lexer yourself is rather complex, maybe filing an issue with Pygmentize would be better. There was a similar issue with Haskell character highlighting (https://github.com/pygments/pygments/issues/71) that is marked resolved but actually also does not work currently, maybe mention that in your new issue.

Comment: Thanks @Marijn! I'll file this with Pygmentize, and in the meantime I can do a workaround using \sbox.